# JS, Object following a circle

Tags: javascript, math, animation, canvas, geometry

I'm trying to get an object to circle around another object. Not too hard, I figured. But it turns out the circle is a spiral... I'm probably using the wrong formula but I am not sure which one I should take instead...

```
var dx = this.x - this.parent.x,
    dy = this.y - this.parent.y,
    r = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

this.x = Math.sin(r) * this.speed + this.x;
this.y = (Math.cos(r) * this.speed * -1) + this.y;
```

When you execute this code, it would appear to work. Each frame the object moves in an arc around it's parent object.

However, the arc gets bigger and bigger, increasing it's distance more and more.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply don't have infinite precision in your float values, and you don't have infinitely small angular steps. So this iterative calculum cannot be exact.

There is no exact iterative solution : if you try to improve the precision with your initial approach, you'll still get a divergence.

The solution is simply to compute each step completely from the angulum, which is easy for a circle :

```
// init part, set your own values
var a = 0; // in radian
var r = 100; // radius, in pixels for example
var da = 1; // in radian. Compute this (once!) using r if you like to use an absolute speed and not a radial one


// each modification
a += da
x = r*Math.sin(a);
y = r*Math.cos(a);
```

Comment: That explains why every change I made basicly made it worse... the code was correct but just not precize enough... how do your variables match to mine, though? a is the angle in degrees, I assume? r the radius and da it's speed?

Comment: It's simply mathematically impossible to be precise enough with this kind of iterative computation.

Comment: a is the angle in radian, r the radius and da the angular speed.

Answer (score 2):

@dystroy's solution is totally legit, but there is a way to constrain your iterative approach so that it doesn't spiral out of control.

Introduce a new variable, R, which is the fixed radius at which you want your object to circle its parent.

```
var hypot = function(x, y) { return Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y); };
//Run this code only once!
var R = hypot(this.x - this.parent.x, this.y - this.parent.y);
```

Then you can add the constraint that the radius of the circle is fixed:

```
//your original code
var dx = this.x - this.parent.x,
    dy = this.y - this.parent.y,
    r = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

//apply constraint:
//calculate what dx and dy should be for the correct radius:
dx = -R * Math.cos(r);
dy = -R * Math.sin(r);

//force this.x, this.y to match that radius.
this.x = this.parent.x + dx;
this.y = this.parent.y + dy;

//the radius will still be off after your update, but
//the amount by which it is off should remain bounded.
this.x = Math.sin(r) * this.speed + this.x;
this.y = (Math.cos(r) * this.speed * -1) + this.y;
```

You could also apply the constraint after updating the position.

Comment: You'll still have a divergence on the total angular position. The basic rule is that you should replace an integral by an approximation by sum only when you can't do otherwise.

Comment: still I don't understand the math behind this iterative approach. Do you have any link?

Comment: @dystroy Yeah, if the point is to get an exact answer, one should probably use an exact formula.  Yes, the angle will be off relative to exact circular motion.  Yes, the point will always be sqrt(R^2 + this.speed^2) away from the center after the velocity update unless you apply the constraint after the velocity update.  I just thought enforcing invariants via explicit constraints is another interesting way to approach the problem.

Comment: @Raffaele the idea is that you add a displacement (think velocity times timestep) to the current position.  The velocity of an object moving in a circle is always tangent to the circle; the particular combination of trig functions and signs here enforces that.  The velocity times time, however, is an approximation and immediately leads the object off a circle.  You can, however, force it to be on the circle again; that's what the middle 4 lines of code do.

Comment: @ellis : yes, that's interesting, I don't deny that.